# Executar função no ng-blur AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, rest

Estou tentando montar um projeto aonde um cliente faz o seu cadastro para ter acesso no sistema, esse cadastro só pode ser realizado se o CPF do cliente existir no banco de dados.

Tenho duas tabelas, `Usuário` e `Beneficiário(Cliente)`. A parte `REST` já está funcionando, porém quero fazer a verificação se o CPF existe assim que o usuário ir para o próximo campo, ou seja, ele preenche o CPF e vai pro campo Senha, se o CPF não existir quero mostrar algum alerta.

Já estou conseguindo recuperar o JSON com os dados do Cliente, porém a função que fiz está sendo executada assim que inicio o sistema e também tenho que passar um CPF fixo como parâmetro.

Resumindo: Quero chamar a função apenas quando acontecer o `ng-blur` e recuperar o cpf.

**routeConfig:**

```
angular.module("unimed").config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        templateUrl: "public/view/login.html",
        controller: "loginController",
        resolve: {
            usuario: function (loginAPI, $route) {

            },
            //Aqui passo o cpf 12345 como parametro
            beneficiarioFind: function(loginAPI, $route){
                return loginAPI.getBeneficiario(12345);
            }
        }   
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: "/login"});

});
```

**LoginAPIService:**

```
angular.module("unimed").factory("loginAPI", function ($http, config) {

    var _getUsuario = function(cpf){
        return $http.get(config.baseURL + "/UnimedWS/usuario/usuario/" +cpf);
    };

    var _saveUsuario = function(usuario){
        return  $http.post(config.baseURL +"/UnimedWS/usuario/", usuario);
    };

    var _getBeneficiario = function(cpf){
        return $http.get(config.baseURL + "/UnimedWS/beneficiario/find/" +cpf);
    };

    return {
        getUsuario: _getUsuario,
        saveUsuario: _saveUsuario,
        getBeneficiario: _getBeneficiario
    };
});
```

---

A cada F5 ou quando abro a página a função é executada, mesmo eu não chamando-a no `controller` e passando ela para o `ng-blur`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu queria que ela fosse chamada aqui (Modal que abre após clicar no botão cadastrar):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando a função no resolve do routeProvider, logo ela vai ser chamada quando a página carregar.

Crie uma função no controller (não citado acima) e chame o mesmo no ng-blur do componente desejado.

Comment: Era isso mesmo, aproveitando a questão. Como faço a verificação pra ver se a requisição retornada é nula?